# Detect if user changes something with web-inspector

Tags: javascript, web-inspector

Is there any way to detect if any change is made by user with web-inspector?
For example, user opens up inspector and changes text inside div in order to fake it. Is there any way to detect it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only have a few elements to watch, use [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

Example usage from the mozilla doc:

```
// Select the node that will be observed for mutations
var targetNode = document.getElementById('some-id');

// Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true };

// Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
var callback = function(mutationsList) {
    for(var mutation of mutationsList) {
        if (mutation.type == 'childList') {
            console.log('A child node has been added or removed.');
        }
        else if (mutation.type == 'attributes') {
            console.log('The ' + mutation.attributeName + ' attribute was modified.');
        }
    }
};

// Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
var observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

// Start observing the target node for configured mutations
observer.observe(targetNode, config);

// Later, you can stop observing
observer.disconnect();
```

Comment: What about content inside it?

Comment: This config seems to work with a text change: `var config = { characterData: false, attributes: false, childList: true, subtree: false };`

Answer (score -3):

Refresh the page to see the original content on the site as changes made by the web inspector is not stored on the server.